# How can i Delete/ remove 1:1 relationship between custom modules and Custom related module using PHP Script (Vtlib Function) from my CRM vtiger 7

Tags: php, vtiger, vtigercrm

I hope all of you are doing well. I have created 1:1 relationship between custom modules and Custom related modules. 1:1 relationship are working fine and relationship view also perfect.
But I want to update related module.  If i add new modules in 1:1 relationship add successfully but   previous module not deleted /removed.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the values of MODULE,RELMODULE and LABEL and run this script.

```
<?php
/*
destroy_relation.php
Create this file into your root directory of vtiger i.e. vtigercrm/
and then run this file directly using your browser 
for example localhost/vtigercrm/destroy_relation.php
 */
include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Menu.php');
include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php');
// Turn on debugging level
$Vtiger_Utils_Log = true;

$moduleInstance = Vtiger_Module::getInstance('MODULE');
$accountsModule = Vtiger_Module::getInstance('RELMODULE');
$relationLabel  = 'LABEL';
$moduleInstance->unsetRelatedList(
      $accountsModule, $relationLabel
);

echo "done";
?>
```